# how to trigger a function on defined date

Tags: php, javascript, triggers, cron

i am doing a project where i need to notify a user through email if his account has expired,
that is when a user signsup his sign up date and expire date is inserted into the database

now what i need to do is , i need to fire a function when the users expire date is passed 
and send an email notifying user about the expiration of his account .
 and this needs to be done automatically through the function .

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: are you talking about using a SQL trigger?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is create a basic cron job that runs on a regular interval (like hourly or daily) that runs a PHP script that queries the database for any newly expired users and then emails them.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a cronjob that runs every hour or so (or quicker if you need to). This cronjob would run a PHP script that gets a list of all expired accounts and sends emails to them.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.adminschoice.com/docs/crontab.htm) on how to use crontab.

Here is a SO question on Cronjob and PHP

- [Getting started with cron jobs and PHP (Zend Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819148/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-and-php-zend-framework)
- [Timed Tasks (cron-like) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318361/timed-tasks-cron-like-in-php)
- [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)
- [What is the best method for scheduled tasks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190561/what-is-the-best-method-for-scheduled-tasks-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Write a cron job (running as often as you think appropriate) to call a script (possibly PHP CLI) that does a select for all expired accounts and mails them.  And what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be using either [at](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) or [cron](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab).  Either one of these could be set up to call a PHP or whatever script at the time of expiration, or it could be just run once an hour, each time checking if there are any newly expired entries.

A less efficient approach would be to have the header or footer script of your pages to check the database every time any page is loaded, but I would not recommend this approach unless you absolutely can't use cron or at.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you are not using a unix / linux system but a Windows one, you could use Scheduled Tasks and call a script.