# HTML5 and NodeJs

Tags: email, node.js

I have website built by html5 and served by Apache, I have installed Nodejs on the same sever.

I want to use node mail to send email each time a html page visited, how can I make the html page to trigger a Nodejs file/program or module?

I just don't know how the HTML page can interact with Nodejs program on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax technology.

Using ajax, you can request an http request trigger your node server to do mail delievery.

Kit

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs is a server side technology. How would you have done it using PHP or Rails? It's the same in principle.

You could for example expose a REST API to call into the server and send a mail, which could then be called from the javascript on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Apache and Node run as two different servers and two different processes.

As described by others, you could use client-side ajax to trigger actions between the two servers. You could use something like dnode that provides RPC (remote procedure calls) between two servers. As described on https://github.com/substack/dnode `There are dnode implementations for perl, ruby, php, and java, so you can glue together all your backend processes swimmingly.`

On the same server you could create a new process. For instance, using PHP you could use `system` or `popen` to call node. ie. `system("node mail.js [args]")`. Make sure to escape your arguments carefully. Here is a popen example: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/Mail/trunk/Mail/sendmail.php?view=markup

Note: I am not sure what advantages using node mail has over using the standard implementation in your apache stack (ie. using PHPjust call `mail()`). If you are looking for non-blocking there are options available in most cases: [Send mail without blocking 'execution'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807518/send-mail-without-blocking-execution)

Comment: I don't use php or any server side scripting, it's just html5 pages and node on the server side as scripting language.